# How can I test that implementations are synchronous or asynchronous where required to be so?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, synchronization

I'm trying to write unit tests around a custom [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) implementation.

The two important operations on this class are `Send` and `Post`, where `Send` invokes a delegate synchronously and `Post` invokes a delegate asynchronously.

I would like to write unit tests to verify this behaviour, that the delegates were executed synchronously or asynchronously. I don't want the tests to rely on delays for success cases, because it artificially prolongs the tests running (but it's reasonable to have failures cause a delay) in execution.

Initially I have considered using Tasks to signal the execution of a delegate:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

var context = new CustomSynchronizationContext();

context.Send((state) => tcs.SetResult(null), null);

// Task should already be completed!
Assert.IsTrue(this.tcs.Task.IsCompleted);
```

However, this does not ensure the delegate was **not** executed asynchronously very quickly before the test runner could continue.

How can I arrange a test around the context to ensure that `Send` blocks for the completion of the delegate and `Post` does not, but that the delegates *are* both invoked?

Comment: +1 for the question and the Name "Tragedian" a person who solve problems... :)

Comment: Isn't it possible to do a postback of the `Thread.ManagedThreadId` that the delegate executed on? If it was the same as the main thread, it was executed synchronously, otherwise async.

Comment: The synchronization context won't run any delegates on the calling thread, so I'm afraid not. Threads are just an implementation detail.

Comment: Maybe unit tests are simply no the right tool for this kind of problem, just like for other multithreaded test cases.

Comment: My primary objective is to assert the behaviour; I'd assumed unit tests were a viable mechanism, but I'm happy to entertain answers that don't go this route.

Comment: Maybe you can do something with OperationCompleted and OperationStarted?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can achieve this using a pair of [ManualResetEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).  Using the code below, the slow down is only experienced if the tests failed (the numbers are pretty high and could probably be reduced safely).  The idea here is that we assert the order in which things must occur that can only happen if we block or don't block.

For the synchronous test:

```
var incall = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var unblock = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var context = new CustomSynchronizationContext();
var t = Task.Run(() => context.Send(state =>
{
    incall.Set();
    unblock.WaitOne(5000);
}, null));
Assert.IsTrue(incall.WaitOne(1000));
Assert.IsFalse(t.Wait(10));
unblock.Set();
Assert.IsTrue(t.Wait(1000));
```

for the Async test:

```
var incall = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var unblock = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var context = new CustomSynchronizationContext();
var t = Task.Run(() =>context.Post(state =>
{
    incall.Set();
    unblock.WaitOne(5000);
}, null));
Assert.IsTrue(incall.WaitOne(1000));
Assert.IsTrue(t.Wait(1000)); //This will timeout if unblock is blocking completion of the task
unblock.Set();
```

Comment: But an asynchornous method could pass your synchronous test, if the timing was right.

Comment: are you referring to the fact that unblock may timeout before and the task completes before the last check or some other issue?

Comment: No, that during your second `Assert()`, the asynchronous method may have already started the execution (so `incall.WaitOne()` completes immediately) but also have not have returned yet, so `Status` will still be `Running`.

Comment: doh, the dangers of trying to reduce the success path execution time too much, waiting 10 milliseconds on the task and asserting that complete is false should do the job...?

Comment: I'm not sure 10 ms is enough, given how thread scheduling works.

Comment: this is just a trade off, pick a number likely to work; write a test that will at least fail some of the time if there is an issue. Part of the problem with proving async code. Perhaps you have a better solution to share?

Answer (score -1):

Incorporating my idea:

```
var mainThreadId = Thread.ManagedThreadId;
var sendThreadId;
context.Send((state) => sendThreadId = Thread.ManagedThreadId);
Assert.AreEqual(mainThreadId, sendThreadId);
```

Don't know if this actually works, you'll have to check.

Comment: The synchronization context won't run any delegates on the calling thread, so I'm afraid not. Threads are just an implementation detail in asynchronous programming.

Comment: Yeah, “synchronous” and “asynchronous” is not the same as “on the same thread” and “on another thread”. Synchronous method could execute the delegate on another thread and the synchronously wait for it to finish.